KDB msum for forward windows?
How do I do a forward version of msum for large time sorted tables without having to reverse the order twice or apply next n times?
t:([] val:100000000?1f);
t:update sym:(count i)?`AA`BB`CC from t;
t:update nextsums: msumfwd[100000;val] by sym from t;

All of these options are slow:
msumfwd:{next reverse x msum reverse y}
msumfwd2:{(x)_ x msum y,x#0}
msumfwd3:{(neg x) xprev (x msum y)}
msumfwd4:{sum 1_(x) next\y}


The example query seems to get a type error with each of the 3 functions. Something missing of incorrect in the code?

@rianoc Fixed the x and y.

I'd be surprised if you can get any faster than the reverse approach (reverse is cheap, and msum is built-in).
I thought that using another built-in would be quick but it's not
q)tl:{sum[x#y]1f\(x _y,x#0)-y};
q)exec a~b from update a:tl[100000;val],b:0^msumfwd[100000;val] by sym from t
1b

Based off of https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#alternative-syntax
Would have been nice if it was faster but alas.
EDIT: this can actually be simplified to
tl:{sum[x#y]+sums(x _y,x#0)-y}

but it's still not faster.
SECOND EDIT: I'll eat my own words, this is very marginally faster
q)tl:{sum[x#y]+sums(0^xprev[neg x;y])-y}
q)\t a:update nextsums:msumfwd[100000;val] by sym from t
3644
q)\t b:update nextsums:tl[100000;val] by sym from t
3278
q)a[`nextsums] cor b`nextsums
1f


What's strange is if you look at a: nextsums1:msumfwd[10000;val], b: nextsums2:tl[100000;val] by sym from t; there is a ~1e-7 difference between a and b even though the cor is 1. Possible floating point error?

Yes, floating point rounding errors - to be expected when dealing with floats. If your numbers were whole numbers you shouldn't see any difference
